# total installations on device count does not update

Tags: android, console

Inside my developer console, my total number of downloads is stuck at 1. It says that it last updated three days ago while google claims it updates everyday.

It is not much but I can confirm my app has at least 20 downloads

What causes this problem?

here is a link to my app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Wyvern.PaperPlane

Comment: i think all data update in weekends or 3-4 days interval. check in these range google play update your app data

Comment: I will wait a couple more days then, I will update my founding